# How to control the strength of an HDRI environment?

Tags: three.js

I'm adding the HDRI with:

```
  import {RGBELoader} from './RGBELoader.js'

  new RGBELoader().load('./assets/images/brown_photostudio_01_1k.hdr', function (texture) {
      texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping
      scene.environment = texture
    })
```

My objects are too bright. How can I dim down the light coming from this HDRI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I dim down the light coming from this HDRI?

Assuming you use `MeshStandardMaterial` or `MeshPhysicalMaterial`, try it with modulating the [envMapIntensity](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.envMapIntensity) material property.

Comment: In addition, an HDR environment map should always be tone mapped, and exposure should be set.

Comment: envMapIntensity works well, thanks!

@WestLangley Right now I'm using global tonemapping on my Renderer. Can HDRIs be tonemapped separately?

Comment: @AlexM No. Tone mapping and exposure are properties of the renderer.